# Dataframe join returns empty results for pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, azure-databricks

I'm trying to join two Spark dataframes (the source of one is a Postgres table, the other a CosmosDB collection), but despite verifying that they both have the key to join on, I don't see the tables joined on this key.

Let's call these dataframes email_df and device_df, respectively:

`email_df.where("id == '123456'").show()`

```
+----------------+--------------------+
|              id|               email|
+----------------+--------------------+
|123456          |customer@gmail.com  |
+----------------+--------------------+
```

`device_df.where("id == '123456'").show()`

```
+----------------+--------------------+
|              id|         device_name|
+----------------+--------------------+
|123456          |Fizzbuzzer 2000     |
+----------------+--------------------+
```

As demostrated above, both dataframes return a row when queried with the id. But when I try to join them as

`email_df.join(device_df, "id", how='left').where(email_df.id == "123456").show()`

it looks like the operation doesn't join the tables where id == '123456' (device_name is left null below):

```
+----------------+--------------------+------------+
|            id  |               email| device_name|
+----------------+--------------------+------------+
|123456          |customer@gmail.com  | null       |
+----------------+--------------------+------------+
```

I'm confused, because I don't see this issue with another cosmosdb-based dataframe that I'm joining with the email_df. Data size shouldn't be an issue either: email_df has ~1M rows, and for the sake of testing, device_df has only 2 rows (rows where the id is '123456'). I've tried broadcast join, without success. Interestingly to me, the small device_df has 79 partitions by default, but coalescing it to one before the join also hasn't had an effect.

Running Databricks cluster version 5.5 LTS / Spark 2.4.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check for spaces that you mag not see visually. That is often the culprit.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, real easy fix.

```py
data1 = [("Finance",10), 
        ("Marketing",20), 
        ("Sales",30), 
        ("IT",40) 
      ]
data2 = [("Finance",45.00), 
        ("Marketing",50.00), 
        ("Sales",15.00), 
        ("IT",90.00) 
      ]
df1 = spark.createDataFrame(data=data1, schema=["dept","heads"])
df2 = spark.createDataFrame(data=data1, schema=["dept","rate"])

# This will return an empty dataframe
df1.join(df2, on="dept")

# This will d what you want it to
df1.join(df2, on=["dept"])
```